# How to apply Angular ngForm to components that are in a recursive relationship?

Tags: angular, forms, validation, recursion, input

I'm a noob, trying to make a simple self-test app for highschool students.

I simply retrieve the exam/test as JSON from the backend (MongoDB+NodeJS) to this ExamComponent:

[ExamComponent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Usv6s.png)

In this ExamComponent that I have circled in red, I then loop over the JSON data which looks like this:

```
"id": 2300,
            "description": "Test description here",
            "part_id": null,
            "test_version": 1,
            "question_id": null,
            "parent_id": null,
            "question_type": "section",
            "title": "Section I  –  LISTENING (20 points)",
            "texts": null,
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": 2301,
                    "description": "Part description here",
                    "part_id": null,
                    "test_version": 1,
                    "question_id": null,
                    "parent_id": "2300",
                    "question_type": "part",
                    "media": "anglicky-jazyk-B1-nahravka-2019-01.mp3",
                    "title": "Part 1: Fashion Designer Isaac Mizrahi (7 points)",
                    "texts": [],
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "description": "What naturally influenced the very young Mizrahi in his love of fashion, was his",
                            "part_id": 1,
                            "test_version": 1,
                            "question_id": 1,
                            "parent_id": "2301",
                            "question_type": "multiple",
                            "media": null,
                            "title": null,
                            "texts": null,
                            "possibilities": [
                                {
                                    "description": "father’s hobby connected with an old family tradition",
                                    "pid": 1,
                                    "ordering": 1,
                                    "qid": 1,
                                    "correct": false,
                                    "correct_value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "description": "father’s occupation and his mother’s love of fashion",
                                    "pid": 2,
                                    "ordering": 2,
                                    "qid": 1,
                                    "correct": true,
                                    "correct_value": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "description": "father’s occupation and his mother’s clothes shop in New York",
                                    "pid": 3,
                                    "ordering": 3,
                                    "qid": 1,
                                    "correct": false,
                                    "correct_value": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "description": "father and mother’s family business located in New York",
                                    "pid": 4,
                                    "ordering": 4,
                                    "qid": 1,
                                    "correct": false,
                                    "correct_value": null
                                }
                            ]
                        }
```

as said, I traverse the JSON tree by looping *ngFor of the entire JSON and @Input the respective "json branches" down to the SubExamComponent (which is visible in the 1st screenshot):

[Looping of JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOi7B.png)
ExamComponent:

```
      <span (click)="openDialog(test_with_questions)" style="cursor: pointer;">✏</span>

    <form #myTemplateVar="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="boom(myTemplateVar)">

        <div *ngFor="let item of test_with_questions; let i = index;">
            <app-sub-exam [model]="item" [parentItemIndex]="i"></app-sub-exam>
        </div>

        <button class="confetti btn" type="submit">Validate answers</button>
    
    </form>
```

The SubExamComponent then renders the JSON like such, and recursively calls itself for more data to be rendered (because of the tree-like structure of the JSON exam):

[Recursive call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4uAh.png)
SubExamComponent:

```
    <span *ngIf="model.question_type == 'list'">
    {{model.question_id}}.) {{model['description']}}
    <div *ngFor="let item of model.possibilities">
        <label> <input type="text" name="{{model.question_id}}" value="{{item['description']}}"
                attr.data-correct="{{item['correct']}}" /> {{item['description']}} </label>
    </div>
</span>


<!-- Recursive call -->
<ng-container *ngIf="model.items">
    <span *ngFor="let item of model.items; let i = index;">
        <app-sub-exam [model]="item" [childPathIndex]="i"></app-sub-exam>
    </span>
</ng-container>
```

I want to be able to click on this button:
[Validate button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDvEd.png)
in the ExamComponent, to check all the inputs entered by the user in the SubExamComponent (which is called recursively).

The trouble I am having is that I don't know how to use any Angular tutorial online, which mostly explain how to work with basic forms, such as logins (e-mail + password), but I need to somehow have unique #id references, to use with my ngForm.

After submitting, by clicking this "Validate answers" button, I'd like to be able to compare the users' input value with this attr.data-correct value from my JSON and simply validate the user's answers on the client side:

[Compare input value with attr.data-corect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE89m.png)

I tried using html # as a reference point to the input fields, but since the exam is rendered recursively, it fails to render, when the # is a fixed name. I need to somehow get the input values in a different way, perhaps with unique # ref tags, or a different method that I'm not aware of. Any guidance will be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you want to show code you can insert them as code snippets because now your question is hard to read with the images.

Comment: why are you using recursive? the json is `section -> question -> possible answers`. What do you expect to happen when you click validate? send data to server or just want to show validation for the answers?

Comment: Hi thx, sorry if I made this question hard to read... new to this.

I am using recursion because the student exams are constructed in a tree-like manner (as you have pointed out:  nth-section -> nth-part -> nth-question -> possible answers[]).

Since the web-app may encounter N exams, consisting of N sections and N parts with N questions and N possible answers.. I am using recursion to read any exam that passes through this exam-component of mine.

Regarding your second question, I do not need to send any data anywhere. I simply want to validate the answers on the client side.

Comment: I would like to compare if the user selected the correct answer (the correct answer is indicated in the JSON above, by the 
"correct": false/true, flag and if it's a question where user input is required, then the "correct_value" flag is what I would like to use.

I simply want to somehow compare the user's input value with the JSON value and check if it's correct on the client side; after that I may simply append a css class of red or deduct/add a point or whatever, to indicate that the answer was (not) correct.